# Preparing training data sets

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, training-data

When preparing a training data set, do I need to remove the target variable data from the training data set or is it fine to leave it in? So, should `X = df[:,:]` in the code below exclude the target variable or does it mater?

```
# Feature to be predicted (y)
y = df['predicted'] #target variable

#Training data
X = df[:,:]

# Perform a 70% train and 30% test data split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = ____(X, y, ____=____)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving or not leaving the target depends on the machine learning library you are using. When creating a training dataset, some libraries give you an option to specify which columns to use for training. In case of these libraries you dont have to remove anything from training data.

Sklearn does not have this option, so you will have to drop the target feature.

```
# Feature to be predicted (y)
y = df['predicted'] #target variable

#Training data
X = df.drop("predicted",1)
# here 1 is the axis which means drop a column

# Perform a 70% train and 30% test data split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = ____(X, y, ____=____)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't leave the label in the features set, you would leak the ready answer.

```
X = df.drop(columns = 'predicted')
```